# How to set Options values to form mapping in Play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I would like to map Option value to form but without ignored.
For instance:

```
case class Message(Id: Option[Int], name: String, description: Option[String])

val messageForm: Form[Message] = Form(
  mapping(
    "id"          -> ignored(Option(0)),
    "name"        -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 4, maxLength = 140),
    "description" -> text
)(Message.apply)(Message.unapply))
          ^

type mismatch;
found   : (Option[Int], String, Option[String]) => Message
required: (Option[Int], String, String)         => ?
```

Ignored "id" value used successful, but 'text' produce errors with apply function.
How correctly do than? need I to write custom form constraints for Option[String]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could transform `Mapping[String]` to `Mapping[Optional[String]]` using `optional` method like this:

```
val messageForm: Form[Message] = Form(
  mapping(
    "id"          -> ignored[Option[Int]](None),
    "name"        -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 4, maxLength = 140),
    "description" -> optional(text)
)(Message.apply)(Message.unapply))
```

Note that you could use `None` to indicate that there is no value in `id` field.